# scrapy startproject error

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, web-crawler, scrapy

I am running into the following error while using the command scrapy startproject to create a project. I am running Python 2.7.6 through canopy on Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit). I have installed all the required dependencies still I cannot find a solution to this. Can anyone help me with this?

```
Python27\Scripts>scrapy startproject ps_localize
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/scrapy", line 7, in <module>
        from scrapy.cmdline import execute
      File "/home/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 9, in <module>
        from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
      File "/home/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 3, in <module>
        from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
      File "/home/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/reactor.py", line 38, in <module>
        from twisted.internet import default
      File "/home/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/default.py", line 56, in <module>
        install = _getInstallFunction(platform)
      File "/home/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/default.py", line 44, in _getInstallFunction
        from twisted.internet.epollreactor import install
      File "/home/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/epollreactor.py", line 24, in <module>
        from twisted.internet import posixbase
      File "/home/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 23, in <module>
        from twisted.internet import error, udp, tcp
      File "/home/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 29, in <module>
        from twisted.internet._newtls import (
      File "/home/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_newtls.py", line 21, in <module>
        from twisted.protocols.tls import TLSMemoryBIOFactory, TLSMemoryBIOProtocol
      File "/home/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py", line 41, in <module>
        from OpenSSL.SSL import Error, ZeroReturnError, WantReadError
      File "/home/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
        from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
      File "/home/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/rand.py", line 11, in <module>
        from OpenSSL._util import (
      File "/home/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 7, in <module>
        binding = Binding()
      File "/home/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 114, in __init__
        self._ensure_ffi_initialized()
      File "/home/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 126, in _ensure_ffi_initialized
        cls._modules,
      File "/home/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/utils.py", line 31, in load_library_for_binding
        lib = ffi.verifier.load_library()
      File "/home/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cffi/verifier.py", line 97, in load_library
        return self._load_library()
      File "/home/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cffi/verifier.py", line 207, in _load_library
        return self._vengine.load_library()
      File "/home/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cffi/vengine_cpy.py", line 155, in load_library
        raise ffiplatform.VerificationError(error)
    cffi.ffiplatform.VerificationError: importing '/home/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.so': /home/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.so: undefined symbol: EC_KEY_clear_flags
```

Comment: I found the solution by running pip install pyOpenSSL==0.13. Thanks